# Codeigniter 3 convert docx to pdf php

Tags: php, codeigniter, converters

I want to convert docx to pdf with codeingiter. My first solution it's install Libre office but now I can not install this on my serveur... (Because my boss doesn't want...)

First solution :

```
$PHPWord = $this->word; // New Word Document
    $document = $PHPWord->loadTemplate('assets/word/' . $select_info->attestation);
    $document->setValue('ID', $insert);
    $document->setValue('lastname', strtoupper($select_info->nom));
    $document->setValue('name', $select_info->prenom);
    $document->setValue('date', date('d/m/Y'));
    $document->save('./'.$select_info->attestation);

    //Avec libraoffice convertir word to pdf
    shell_exec('start /wait soffice --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir "." "./test.docx"');
```

Any idea ? Thanks

Comment: please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

CI is just a lightweight framework and doesn't include anything to do what you want.  You will need to install something to make this work.  You could try the library here: https://github.com/phpgearbox/pdf

Comment: Thanks but i can not use this :
 "DOCX: If you are going to be using the DOCX templating you will need to install either libre-office-headless or unoconv on your host."
It is necessary to install libre office :/.. Thanks for your reply